# Select DISTINCT field when using PATINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called `Issues` that I need to get data from.  I am joining the Issues table with another table called `IssueActivities`.  So for each instance of an IssueID, there could be 1 to many IssueActivities.  In the `IssueActivities` table is a field called `Notes` and it is of datatype `text`.  I'm trying to select a DISTINCT list of IssueID's where the Notes field DOES NOT contain 2 particular string.

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.IssueID
FROM Issues i
INNER JOIN IssueActivities ia ON i.IssueID = ia.IssueID
WHERE i.IssueStatusID = 2 --Closed issues only
AND (PATINDEX('%Pending DR%', ia.Notes) < 1 AND PATINDEX('%Pending E%', ia.Notes) < 1)
```

The problem with this sql is that it returns IssueID's for issues that have that criteria because of the fact an Issue can have **many** IssueActivities, so not all the rows contain that criteria.  Does that make sense?  Here's a quick example:

**Issues table**

```
IssueID | IssueStatusID
-----------------------
1700       2
1701       2
```

**IssueActivities table**

```
IssueActivityID | IssueID | Notes
---------------------------------
1                 1700      Issue Entered
2                 1700      Sub Status changed from New to In Progress
3                 1700      Sub Status changed from In Progress to Pending DR
4                 1701      Issue Entered
5                 1701      Issue Assigned
6                 1701      Sub Status changed from New to Closed
```

So from the above table, I would like to get only issue 1701 because of all the IssueActivities that belong to it, none of them contain the criteria that I am using.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the rows you want to exclude, then eliminate them in the where clause. This example uses `APPLY` to find any IssueActivity row with "Pending DR" or "Pending E" in it for each Issues row. Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/acfcd/1)

```
SELECT i.IssueID
FROM Issues i
OUTER APPLY(
  SELECT TOP 1 ia.IssueActivityID
  FROM IssueActivities ia
  WHERE ia.IssueID = i.IssueID
    AND (PATINDEX('%Pending DR%', ia.Notes) > 0
      OR PATINDEX('%Pending E%', ia.Notes) > 0)
) pending
WHERE i.IssueStatusID = 2
  AND pending.IssueActivityID IS NULL
```

Comment: HA, you beat me to the fiddle...here's mine (using somewhat real data) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d853e/4.  I've never used APPLY before, can you briefly explain it?

Comment: Sure, APPLY is a table-valued function that you can join to each row of a query. There is CROSS APPLY, which is like an inner join that limits the result set of the main query. OUTER APPLY as seen here will not limit the main query's result set if nothing is returned by the APPLY. I find that APPLY is particularly useful with SELECT TOP queries to find things like the most recently edited row based on a datetime column. Here is a good explanation: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-apply-basics/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to first select what you want to ignore:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IssueID
FROM IssuesActivities
WHERE PATINDEX('%Pending DR%', ia.Notes) > 0 OR PATINDEX('%Pending E%', ia.Notes) > 0
```

Then you can ignore it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.IssueID
FROM Issues i
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT IssueID
           FROM IssuesActivities
           WHERE PATINDEX('%Pending DR%', ia.Notes) > 0 OR PATINDEX('%Pending E%', ia.Notes) > 0
          )ia
  ON i.IssueID = ia.IssueID
WHERE i.IssueStatusID = 2 --Closed issues only
   AND ia.IssueID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your reference to `IssueActivities` with a subquery that returns only the records from that table that you *don't* want to include, change the join an outer join so as to return all records from `Issues`, and change your criteria to return `Issues` records only where the `IssueActivity` query *doesn't* have matching records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.IssueID
FROM Issues AS i LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT * FROM IssueActivities WHERE (PATINDEX('%Pending DR%', ia.Notes) < 1)
       AND (PATINDEX('%Pending E%', ia.Notes) < 1)) AS ia ON i.IssueID = ia.IssueID
WHERE (i.IssueStatusID = 2) AND ia.IssueID IS NULL
```

You could also use:

```
SELECT i.IssueID
FROM Issues AS i
WHERE (i.IssueStatusID = 2) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM IssueActivities AS ia 
WHERE (PATINDEX('%Pending DR%', ia.Notes) < 1) AND (PATINDEX('%Pending E%', ia.Notes) < 1)
      AND (i.IssueID = ia.IssueID)) )
```